# How to inject into message inspector using Unity?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, dependency-injection, unity-container, idispatchmessageinspector

I am currently using Unity as DI container for an ASP MVC 3 application. As I have to expose some functionality as web service I already wrote some WCF services. This works quite well. In order to secure the web service I'd like to use the concept of message inspectors. So far this works as well but now I'd like to inject some service class' instance into the message inspector in order to invoke its functionality (e.g. checking credentials). Unfortunately I have really no idea how to inject the service.

I have read about the Unity.WCF package but not quite sure if this will work from the very beginning or where to adapt this approach respectively.

Does anyone know how to do this?